# sql left outer join order by column in left table but preserve all rows

Tags: sql, join

I have the following:

```
SELECT 
table1.id
FROM
table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table2.table1_id = table1.id
WHERE
(table1.entry_id=2) 
AND 
parent_id=0 
ORDER BY 
SUM(table2.column1) - SUM(table2.column2)
```

Works fine until I add the 'order by', I need it to get all relevant rows from table1, even if they have unmatched rows in table2, ordering would place them at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
   SELECT table1_id, SUM(column1) sum1, SUM(column2) sum2
   FROM table2 
   GROUP BY table1_id
) AS t2  ON t2.table1_id = t.id
        AND t1.entry_id  = 2 
        AND t1.parent_id = 0 
ORDER BY t2.sum1 - t2.sum2;
```